# Pass values from database to user uploaded HTML

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Updated with current Code*

I thought i would ask for your assistance regarding my issue.

Im wondering how i may go about replacing content that is contained in one column and take the value of another along with its own.

I have the following code and,

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Template</th>
      <th>SaleID</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>User Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
     $res = $MySQLiconn->query("SELECT * FROM crud WHERE uid='{$_SESSION['userSession']}' ORDER BY id DESC");
     while($row=$res->fetch_array())
      {
      ?>
    <tr>
      <td><!-- THIS COL WILL BE HTML CONTENT A USER UPLOADED ALREADY WHICH SHOULD HAVE THE OTHER VALUES MIXED IN (price, des, title) --></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['saleid']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['des']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['price']; ?></td>
    <?php
     if($row['status']=='Listed')
      echo "<td><span class='label label-success'>".$row['status']."</span></td>"; 
     else if($row['status']=='Awaiting')
      echo "<td><span class='label label-warning'>".$row['status']."</span></td>";
    ?>
      <td><a href="?view=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" role="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" ><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a> <a href="?edit=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="return confirm('Want to edit?'); " ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a> <a href="?del=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" role="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="return confirm('Confirm Delete!'); " ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
     <?php
      }
     ?>

   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You want to do it with PHP?

Comment: You need a model which takes the data from your MySQL, ex Select * frommytable WHERE name ="John" and then from your controller you need to pass this data to the view file. Anyway we need your code - model and controller to help.

Comment: Anyway really i can get this to show, @tiky i know a query can be used to to pull the data for "John" but my question would be how to pass the col name name or whatever it may be to the template value.

Comment: So you know how to do the SQL request from controller, but you do not know how to pass the value to the view? Can you show me the fragment of your controller where you pulling the data from SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

Model

```
public function select_data($id) {  
  $this->db->select(*); //or any fields
  $this->db->where('id', $id);
  $query = $this->db->get('table_name');
  return $query->row_array();               
}
```

Controller:

```
$data = $this->your_model_name->select_data($id); /id of the specified person
//pass data to the view
$this->load->view('your_view_file', $data);
```

View:

```
//display name or description where 'desc' is your filed name from DB
<? echo $data['desc'] ?>
```

or mix this with your static data:

```
<p>
    My name is <? echo $data['name'] ?>.
</p>
<p>
    Description of the person: <? echo $data['desc'] ?>
</p>
```

Comment: Hi Tikky, your example shows as i see how to echo the data but im wondering if the data <? echo $data['desc'] ?> can be included in the next column along with its own content. Please see my update example 2

Comment: Of course. You can use this data in your view like:
<h1>My First Bootstrap Page by <? echo $data['desc']  ?> </h1>. See above updated example.

Comment: Update, i have opted to use PHP for this, Tikky i can understand your question but this relates to where the user uploads a template such as html code, so for example they will have <h1>Made by {name}</h1>, i want the Name to be pulled from the name column in the database. I know i could use <?php echo $row['name']; ?> but the user cannot submit it like that and wont work.